# Run a calc using a list of inputs, and record the results against the input values

Tags: excel, vba

Need vba to look at the list residing in D28:D40, take the first value (D28), paste into $D$4 for processing. Copy the output from $D$23 and paste it into E28 (adjacent to the input value). 
Run next value D29, get the result from D23 and paste result in E29.
Lop until end of list.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

consider:

```
Sub dural()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 28 To 40
    Range("D4").Value = Range("D" & i).Value
    DoEvents
    Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D23").Value
  Next i
End Sub
```